# Sharepoint form on IOS

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have a Sharepoint form that will not open on iOS. Other forms do but not this one and I get this error. Can anyone help? [image][image]

Comment: Can you update your tags to include the version of SharePoint that you are using and clarify what kind of form and what 'app' you are using within SharePoint (i.e. Document Library, Form Library, List)?

Comment: What is different between the problematic form and the working ones? Different site, content source, content page/page layout, file name characters, etc.?